# HAVING clause in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm rewriting the MySQL queries to PostgreSQL. I have table with articles and another table with categories. I need to select all categories, which has at least 1 article:

```
SELECT c.*,(
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM articles a 
    WHERE a."active"=TRUE AND a."category_id"=c."id") "count_articles" 
FROM articles_categories c 
HAVING (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM articles a 
    WHERE a."active"=TRUE AND a."category_id"=c."id" ) > 0
```

I don't know why, but this query is causing an error:

```
ERROR:  column "c.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function at character 8
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `HAVING` clause is a bit tricky to understand. I'm not sure about how MySQL interprets it. But the Postgres documentation can be found here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-HAVING

It essentially says:

> The presence of HAVING turns a query
>   into a grouped query even if there is
>   no GROUP BY clause. This is the same
>   as what happens when the query
>   contains aggregate functions but no
>   GROUP BY clause. All the selected rows
>   are considered to form a single group,
>   and the SELECT list and HAVING clause
>   can only reference table columns from
>   within aggregate functions. Such a
>   query will emit a single row if the
>   HAVING condition is true, zero rows if
>   it is not true.

[The same is also explained in this blog post](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/04/do-you-really-understand-sqls-group-by-and-having-clauses/), which shows how `HAVING` without `GROUP BY` implicitly implies a SQL:1999 standard "grand total", i.e. a `GROUP BY ( )` clause (which isn't supported in PostgreSQL)

Since you don't seem to want a *single row*, the `HAVING` clause might not be the best choice.

Considering your actual query and your requirement, just rewrite the whole thing and `JOIN` `articles_categories` to `articles`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM articles_categories c
JOIN articles a 
ON a.active = TRUE 
AND a.category_id = c.id
```

alternative:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles_categories c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM articles a
               WHERE a.active = TRUE 
                 AND a.category_id = c.id)
```

Comment: But this results has to be grouped anyway or i have to use DISTINCT(), don't i?

Comment: Yes, of course. I'm sorry... I corrected the query and provided an alternative

Comment: `HAVING` without `GROUP BY` is legal in SQL and also supported by PostgreSQL.  This has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @Peter, you are right. I didn't know that. Thanks for the hint. The Postgres documentation states that adding a `HAVING` clause enforces an implicit `GROUP BY` if there isn't any `GROUP BY` clause: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-HAVING. It also states that: `Such a query will emit a single row if the HAVING condition is true, zero rows if it is not true.`. So it has all the more to do with the problem. You can upvote me again :-)

Comment: @Lukas Eder: Done. :)  Your updated answer is right on target.

Comment: Awesome! :) Thanks again for the hint. One always learns on stackoverflow, even when answering questions...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM categories c
WHERE
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM article a WHERE c.id = a.category_id);
```

should be fine... perhaps simpler ;)

Comment: Could you please explain your query? How does it fix the author problem?